# React ssr: 'You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering

I am trying to convert my Client side rendered app to a server-side-rendered app. The conversion is going well only that I stumbled upon one problem.

[image: test: /.js$|jsx/,]

When looking this error up, I come around stackoverflows that says I need to add a webpack.config.js file, so I did, tried multiple variations of code in it. But nothing works.

Here is my webpack.config.js file:

```
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'src/client/index.js'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        filename: 'client.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'src/client'),
        publicPath: '/dist/'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js'],
        alias: {
            components: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'src/components'),
        }
    },
    module: {

        // apply loaders to files that meet given conditions
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$|jsx/,
            include: path.join(__dirname, '/client/src'),
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ["react", "es2015", "stage-1"]
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.(gif|svg|jpg|png)$/,
            loader: "file-loader",
        }],
    },
};
```

Anyone know what I should add to my webpack.config.js file? or is there another solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use [url-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-loader) or [file-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-loader) to match the png file you want to load.

```
{
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        loaders: [
          'file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
          'url-loader?limit=8192'
        ]
}
```